# Listagg two columns + group them when same values are shared

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm working on Oracle SQL-Developer.

Let's start with data to better describe my issue. I have a table with 2 columns

```
USER
JOB
```

The relationship between those 2 is 1,n. So 1 user can relate to 1 or more JOB and 1 JOB be related to 1 or more USER.

Here a sample of the data :

```
USER  JOB 
  1     A     
  1     B      
  1     C      
  1     D      
  1     E
  2     B
  2     C
  2     F
  2     G
  3     A
  3     B
  3     C
  3     D
  4     I
  4     J
  4     K
  4     L
```

The idea is to retrieve interconnected values all together. First of all, I though about LISTAGG that can concatenate and group values.
But I'm obtaining this kind of result:

```
 USER  JOB 
  1     A, B, C, D, E     
  2     B, C, F, G
  3     A, B, C, D
  4     I, J, K, L
```

OR

```
USER        JOB 
  1, 3        A     
  1, 2, 3     B      
  1, 2, 3     C      
  1, 3        D      
  1           E      
  2           F
  2           G
  4           I
  4           J
  4           K
  4           L
```

The desired output is the following:

```
USER        JOB
1, 2, 3     A, B, C, D, E, F, G
4           I, J, K, L
```

The idea is that if a user shares one job with someone else, then all jobs are linked all together even if all JOBS are not the same.

Example: `USER_1` has 2 jobs A and B. `USER_2` has 2 jobs B and C. Then `USER_1` and `USER_2` share jobs A, B, C.

Reversely, if a job shares one user with another job, then all users are linked all together even if all USERS are not the same...

So I've tried self join in order to retrieve all job for one given user and all users for one job given in order to display all possible shared values, but maybe it's the wrong way because
I'm still blocked with LISTAGG. I've thought about PIVOT too but not tried it yet.

I hope I made this clear. What do you all think?

Comment: You want components of the graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory).  Although it's quite possible to create a pl/sql  procedure, sql is not the best tool for the task frankly.

Comment: Hello @Serg, thank you for the reply. You are absolutely right. I though of creating pl/sql procedure, but i don't have the permission on my database to create one... That's why I'm trying to resolve it through sql.

Answer (score 4):

This is not going to be efficient for large data sets but you can use a hierarchical query to find the groups each belongs to and then find the distinct users/jobs in each group and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH groups ( grp, "USER", job ) AS (
  SELECT MIN(CONNECT_BY_ROOT("USER")) AS grp,
         "USER",
         JOB
  FROM   table_name
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR "USER" = "USER"
  OR     PRIOR JOB = JOB
  GROUP BY "USER", JOB
)
SELECT users,
       jobs
FROM   (
         SELECT grp,
                LISTAGG("USER", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "USER") AS users
         FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT grp, "USER"
           FROM   groups
         )
         GROUP BY grp
       ) u
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT grp,
                LISTAGG(JOB, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY JOB) AS jobs
         FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT grp, job
           FROM   groups
         )
         GROUP BY grp
       ) j
       ON ( u.grp = j.grp );
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "USER", JOB ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'J' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'L' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USERS | JOBS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1,2,3 | A,B,C,D,E,F,G |
> | 4 | I,J,K,L |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fc18855fa24550d6a562bd5fbf70bde)*

Comment: Oh thank you ! Very fast reply. I'll try on my real dataset and i give you a feedback

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not an answer for *Oracle SQL-Developer*, but may point you out in an other direction that works fine even if you see that the *pure SQL* solution hits a performance wall for larger data (my experience).

I'm using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) and the library [igraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) to solve the problem of *graph partitioning*.

To get the data in `R` is somehow similar to SQL*Plus (skipping the details of the [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) installation and connection setup).

```
df <-  dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 
"select * from table_name")

> df
   USER JOB
1     1   A
2     1   B
3     1   C
4     1   D
5     1   E
...
```

Now load the data in the *undirected graph* and visualize it

```
gg <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df), directed=F)
plot(gg)
```

[image]

Now perform the partitioning - basically showing the connected subgraphs from above

```
> split(V(gg)$name, clusters(gg)$membership)
$`1`
 [1] "1" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "2" "F" "G" "3"

$`2`
[1] "4" "I" "J" "K" "L"
```

This is not the exact result as the users and jobs must be splitted but this should not be the major problem.